# The easiest way to replace white spaces with (underscores) _ in bash

Tags: bash, sed

recently I had to write a little script that parsed VMs in XenServer and as the names of the VMs are mostly with white spaces in e.g Windows XP or Windows Server 2008, I had to trim those white spaces and replace them with underscores _ . I found a simple solution to do this using sed which is great tool when it comes to string manipulation.

```
echo "This is just a test" | sed -e 's/ /_/g'
```

returns

```
This_is_just_a_test
```

Are there other ways to accomplish this?

Comment: and the question is ?

Comment: Hi latz, Stackoverflow is a questions and answers site. You ask questions and others answer it, or you can answer questions from others. If you want to share your knowledge, you can ask a question, then answer it yourself (after leaving some time for others to answer as well).

Comment: oups thought I would add this knowledge that way so it is stored here. Anyway will do it like u said next time, by answering my own question :)

Answer (score 200, accepted):

You can do it using only the shell, no need for `tr` or `sed`

```
$ str="This is just a test"
$ echo ${str// /_}
This_is_just_a_test
```

Comment: Or convert all non-ASCII word chars to underscores: `${str//[^a-zA-Z0-9]/_}`; either way, if you're not sticking to pure POSIX shell, then use the features available to you.

Comment: there might be punctuations that are legit as well. we never know.

Answer (score 22):

This is borderline programming, but look into using [tr](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr):

```
$ echo "this is just a test" | tr -s ' ' | tr ' ' '_'
```

Should do it. The first invocation squeezes the spaces down, the second replaces with underscore. You probably need to add TABs and other whitespace characters, this is for spaces only.