# How to convert user input spaces to dashes

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that takes user input from the following line of code.

```
echo "What is the customer name?"
read hostname
```

When a user running the script answers the question with:

```
Company A in Texas
```

How can I have the script convert the spaces into dashes like this?

```
Company-A-in-Texas
```

I could run processing to do this with a file but I am drawing a blank when it comes to having the script do this. I suppose I could send the data to stdout and then run processing on it. Just trying to get some other ideas.

Comment: This is done trivially with `tr` but what is the goal of this transformation? What are you going to do with the customer name after replacing spaces with hyphens? If you're going to create a file, you will need to do a lot more to sanitize the user input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ read -p "What is the customer name? " custname
What is the customer name? Company A in Texas
$ custname=${custname// /-}
$ echo "$custname"
Company-A-in-Texas
```

I have replaced `echo` plus `read` with `read -p`<sup>1</sup> (for "prompt") and renamed your parameter, as `hostname` is the name of a command, which could lead to confusion.

To replace the spaces with dashes, I've used [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion); notice the double slash to make sure all spaces are replaced, and not just the first one.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Notice that the `-p` option is Bash specific and not specified for the POSIX shell.</sub>

Comment: So what happens if the user input already includes the dashes? Will it ignore the new formatting? The end goal is to create the file later on in the script using the dashes. But I do not want to mess this up if a user has already included them.

Comment: @user53029 It just replaces every space with a dash, nothing else. Existing dashes are untouched.

Comment: @user53029 See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167155/comments-asking-for-upvotes-accepts

Comment: I'm just pointing out that if the community thinks a question is good, the upvotes will come, no need to ask for them. I don't think your question is horrible, but it's not excellent either. There are many almost-duplicates, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706431/the-easiest-way-to-replace-white-spaces-with-underscores-in-bash) or [this one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162221/shortest-way-to-replace-characters-in-a-variable), which lets me doubt the "research effort" bit mentioned in the upvote criterium.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done using `tr`

```
tr " " "-" <<< "Company A in Texas"
```

which outputs

```
Company-A-in-Texas
```

Adding it in a script:-

```
#!/bin/bash


echo "What is the customer name?"
read hostname
echo "$hostname" | tr " " "-"
```

will output as the OP needs.

Comment: You can delete that line that sets `$var`.

Comment: Also, you need to double quote `$hostname` on the last line, in case the user inputs something that contains a shell globbing character.

Comment: Me neither. Someone with a pet peeve about something maybe? Here-strings or not using `-r` with read or whatever?